# show a function is continuous at irrational point

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]=\{r_1,r_2,r_3,...\}$ (We can do this because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \subset \mathbb{Q}$. Let $x \in (0,1)$. Define $$f(x)=\sum_{r_n<x}{\frac{1}{2^n}}$$ Show that

a) $f$ is continuous at every irrational point $x \in (0,1) $.

b) $f$ is discontinuous at every rational point $x \in (0,1)$.

My attempt:

a) What I'm trying to show here is that the left-hand limit and the right-hand limit exist and they are equal.

Let $a \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$. Note that $|f(a+\delta)-f(a)|=\sum_{a < r_n < a + \delta}{\frac{1}{2^n}}$. We have $a < r_n$ because $a$ is irrational. Also $\frac{1}{2^n}>0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, we have $\sum_{a < r_n < a + \delta}{\frac{1}{2^n}}<\frac{1}{2^N}+\frac{1}{2^{N+1}}+...=\frac{\frac{1}{2^N}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}$. By taking $\delta=\log_2(\frac{2}{\epsilon})$, we have shown that the right-hand limit of $f$ exists. By applying the same argument, we can show that $|f(a)-f(a-\delta)|<\epsilon$

b) Let $a \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then we have $|f(a+\delta)-f(a)|=\sum_{a \leq r_n < a + \delta}{\frac{1}{2^n}}$. Then I don't know how to proceed from here.

Can someone help me to verify my attempt above for part a)? Also can someone give some hints on how to continue part b)?

Comment: For $b$: If $r$ is rational, then $r$ corresponds to one of the terms in the sum $f(r+)$, but not to the sum $f(r-)$.

Comment: Your argument for a) is missing something.  For one, you haven't defined $n$.  You want to take $n$ minimal such that $\alpha < r_n < \alpha + \delta$.  Call it $n_\delta$.  Argue that, given $\epsilon$, you can take $\delta$ small enough such that $n_\delta$ is large enough for $\frac{1}{2^{n_\delta - 1}} < \epsilon$ to hold.

Comment: This is the same question, except it works with all rationals not only in $[0,1]$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421220/proving-a-function-is-continuous-on-all-irrational-numbers Some other similar questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421750/a-problem-on-continuity-of-a-function-on-irrarationals and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253529/real-analysis-question-continuity